# How to change Android Theme color (colorPrimaryDark) in reactjs

Tags: android, reactjs, android-room

I am new in android development , I want to change the theme color

```
<!-- change it from here theme color. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/lightBlue</item>

    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>

    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="Dialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#333333</item>
</style>
```

Here is my color code : #ec6d7e

I want to set #ec6d7e that code in colorPrimaryDark , but it gives me error ;

> No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark' with value '@color/#ec6d7e')

Please help for changing the theme color, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to `app > src > main > res > values` and create `colors.xml`.

Add your colours, like so:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ec6d7e</color>
</resources>
```

Then you'll be able to reference it via `@color/colorPrimaryDark`.